# Whenever I try to install modules using pip an error occurs

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, pip

I was trying to install tkinter in python 2.7 on Windows 7 using pip. At the time I gave the install command in command prompt it returned :
'Pip' name is not specified
Please help

Comment: Please show us the command you issue and the output instead of paraphrasing, this makes it easier to see what you are doing and what your system says is wrong.

Comment: You cannot install tkinter with pip.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd as administrator and run python.In python shell type "pip install python3-tk"(without quotes).
U will see tkinter getting installed.
also make sure to type pip in lowercase and not in uppercase